# Laravel Eloquent relationship hasonethrough return an empty array

Tags: php, eloquent, foreign-keys, relationship

I use Eloquent through the library illuminate/database, not Laravel.

I have an users table, a stripe_customer_ids table where I save the stripe customer id once Stripe generate it and a user_stripe_subscriptions table where I save the details about the subscriptions.

I need to retrieve the user's subscription id in the user_stripe_subscriptions table with the user's data in the users table.

I tried changing many options in foreign key and local key options following the Laravel documentation but the query still return an empty array.

This is the relationship I setted in the User model:

```php
public function userStripeSubscription() {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('\App\Models\UserStripeSubscription', '\App\Models\StripeCustomerId', 'user_id', 'stripe_customer_id', 'id', 'id');
    }
```

In the StripeCustomerId model the relationship with the User model is setteb by:

```php
public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, "user_id", "id");
    }
```

and the relationship with UserStripeSubscription is setted by:

```php
public function userStripeSubscriptions() {
        return $this->hasOne(UserStripeSubscription::class, 'stripe_customer_id', 'stripe_customer_id');
    }
```

In the UserStripeSubscription model there is the relationship with the StripeCustomerId model:

```php
public function stripeCustomerId() {
        return $this->belongsTo(StripeCustomerId::class, "stripe_customer_id", "stripe_customer_id");
    }
```

Obviously the table are correctly populated so I expect to get a result with this code:

```php
$user   = User::where('id', $userId)->with('userStripeSubscription')->first();
```

but I only get the user's array and an empty array like this:

```php
["relations":protected]=>
  array(1) {
    ["userStripeSubscription"]=>
    object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)#40 (1) {
      ["items":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
    }
  }
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second local key is incorrect:

```
public function userStripeSubscription()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        '\App\Models\UserStripeSubscription', '\App\Models\StripeCustomerId',
        'user_id', 'stripe_customer_id',
        'id', 'stripe_customer_id'
    );         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

Comment: That was an error in copying the code. I've set it to 'id' but the result is the same...

Comment: Have you logged the executed queries?

Comment: mhmh... no. How can I do it with Eloquent?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/database#listening-for-query-events or https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar

Comment: Your first reply is correct! It was my mistake! The session was expired so it gave me NULL as the $userId variable was empty. 
Thank you very much and thank you also for showing me the way to debug the query